# With Google Cloud Vision, any limitation of width and length in Text_Detection and any way to specify the texts within a picture?

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I am stuck with a couple of problems when using Google Cloud Vision.

After I have tested Text_Detection with the Google Platform, I have had the results that I wanted in many cases. However, sometimes I fail to have the intended result either when it's too wide or long. Is there any limit to length or width, or resolution to get a proper result?

Also is there any way to recognize the texts within a specific area of a picture?

If anyone knows about the issue that I am facing now, please enlighten me. :)
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a picture you can post that did not get the intended result. We do have recommended resolutions for OCR on https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs - under best practice